# Git: patch cannot apply - missing header info

Tags: git, patch, git-am

I'm getting this error when trying to apply a patch using `git am`:

```
error: git diff header lacks filename information
when removing 1 leading pathname component (line 9)
```

The patch was created using git's own `format-patch` command and not edited in any way, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but apparently git patches rely on them.

It should no longer be an issue:

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/15108de2fa0cd8f002a0551d14c84505a853071c/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch))</sup> honors the `src/dst` prefixes set to nonstandard values with configuration variables like `diff.noprefix`, causing the receiving end of the patch that expects the standard `-p1` format to break.
Teach "`format-patch`" to ignore end-user configuration and always use the standard prefixes.

This is a backward compatibility breaking change.

See [commit ab89575](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab89575387c02ea024163256826ad1c6dd2e4247) (13 Mar 2023), and [commit 8d5213d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d5213decff887b2d950b732e37b7abad6f8d450), [commit c169af8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c169af8f7ab521cc47b59f104db78847e324a3cb), [commit b39a569](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b39a5697296659c344cd0a286b51303fd5375fab), [commit 7c03d0d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c03d0db8807d303540297432455adfa1c45b05e), [commit 6799aad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6799aadfdf484135476aaf74f5d2eb825d9f00e8) (09 Mar 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 15108de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15108de2fa0cd8f002a0551d14c84505a853071c), 21 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c169af8f7ab521cc47b59f104db78847e324a3cb): do not respect `diff.noprefix`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The output of format-patch respects `diff.noprefix`, but this usually ends up being a hassle for people receiving the patch, as they have to manually specify "`-p0`" in order to apply it.
>
> I don't think there was any specific intention for it to behave this way.
> The noprefix option is handled by `git_diff_ui_config()`, and `format-patch` exists in a gray area between plumbing and porcelain.
>
> People do look at the output, and we'd expect it to colorize things, respect their choice of algorithm, and so on.
> But this particular option creates problems for the receiver (in theory so does `diff.mnemonicprefix`, but since we are always formatting commits, the mnemonic prefixes will always be "`a/`" and "`b/`").
>
> So let's disable it.
> The slight downsides are:
>
> - people who have set `diff.noprefix` presumably like to see their patches without prefixes.
>   If they use `format-patch` to review their series, they'll see prefixes.
>   On the other hand, it is probably a good idea for them to look at what will actually get sent out.
>
>   We could try to play games here with "is stdout a tty", as we do for
>   color.
>   But that's not a completely reliable signal, and it's
>   probably not worth the trouble. If you want to see the patch with
>   the usual bells and whistles, then you are better off using "`git log`" or "`git show`".
> - if a project really does have a workflow that likes prefix-less patches, and the receiver is prepared to use "`-p0`", then the sender now has to manually say "`--no-prefix`" for each format-patch invocation.
>   That doesn't seem *too* terrible given that the receiver has to manually say "`-p0`" for each [`git-am`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c169af8f7ab521cc47b59f104db78847e324a3cb/Documentation/git-am.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup> invocation.

And:

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d5213decff887b2d950b732e37b7abad6f8d450): add format.noprefix option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The previous commit dropped support for `diff.noprefix` in `format-patch`.
> While this will do the right thing in most cases (where sending patches without a prefix was an accidental side effect of the sender preferring to see their local patches without prefixes), it left no good option for a project or workflow where you really do want to send patches without prefixes.
> You'd be stuck using "`--no-prefix`" for every invocation.
>
> So let's add a config option specific to `format-patch` that enables this behavior.
> That gives people who have such a workflow a way to get what they want, but makes it hard to accidentally trigger it.
>
> A more backwards-compatible way of doing the transition would be to have format.noprefix default to diff.noprefix when it's not set.
> But that doesn't really help the "accidental" problem; people would have to manually set `format.noprefix=false`.
> And it's unlikely that anybody really wants `format.noprefix=true` in the first place.
> I'm adding it here mostly as an escape hatch, not because anybody has expressed any interest in it.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d5213decff887b2d950b732e37b7abad6f8d450/Documentation/config/format.txt#L147-L153):

> ### `format.noprefix`
>
> If set, do not show any source or destination prefix in patches.
> This is equivalent to the `diff.noprefix` option used by `git diff` (but which is not respected by `format-patch`). Note that
> by setting this, the receiver of any patches you generate will
> have to apply them using the `-p0` option.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out it was because I had **disabled filename prefixes** in git diff output (`noprefix = true` in your `.gitconfig`). They are not useful when reading `git diff` output, but apparently git patches rely on them.

You can check what's your setting with

```
git config --get diff.noprefix
```

If it returns `true`, try disabling the setting with

```
git config --global diff.noprefix false
```

(you can omit `--global` flag if you want to make a change only for current repo).

Patches generated afterwards worked fine for me.

Comment: Did not work for me unfortunately...